# Matching groups in bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

In bash I have the following:

```
REGEX="(1.0.0|2.0.0)"
declare -a arr=("A:1.0.0" "B:1.0.0" "C:2.0.0" "D:2.0.1")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "Found: $i"
    if [[ "$i"=~"${REGEX}" ]]; then
        echo "$i matches: ${REGEX}"
    else
        echo "$i DOES NOT match: ${REGEX}"
    fi   
done
```

I would assume that for `D:2.0.1` it would print `...DOES NOT match...` but instead it prints

```
Found: A:1.0.0
A:1.0.0 matches: (1.0.0|2.0.0)
Found: B:1.0.0
B:1.0.0 matches: (1.0.0|2.0.0)
Found: C:2.0.0
C:2.0.0 matches: (1.0.0|2.0.0)
Found: D:2.0.1
D:2.0.1 matches: (1.0.0|2.0.0)
```

So what is wrong with my REGEX group pattern? Specifying a group pattern like that works fine in other languages - e.g. like groovy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a a typo in the regex match expression to start with

```
if [[ "$i"=~"${REGEX}" ]]; then
```

should have been written as just

```
if [[ $i =~ ${REGEX} ]]; then
```

which implicates the point that you should *never* quote your regex expressions. For it to understand the `|` operator in its extended regular expressions support(ERE) you need to make it understand that it is not a literal string which it treats so when under double-quotes.

---

#### Not recommended

But if you still want to quote your regex strings - [`bash` 3.2 introduced a compatibility option `compat31` (under New Features in Bash 1.l)](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) which reverts bash regular expression quoting behavior back to 3.1 which supported quoting of the regex string. You just need to enable it via an extended shell option

```
shopt -s compat31
```

and run it with quotes now

```
if [[ $i =~ "${REGEX}" ]]; then
```